# Algorithm to count how many obs there are between two events

Tags: python, algorithm

I need to develop an algorithm which is able to count how many "days" passes from one event (with the occurrencies True/False stored in the list *Vec1*) to another event (with the occurrencies True/False stored in the list *Vec2*). The two lists are as follows:

```
Vec1 = [True, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, False, True, False, True, False, False, False, True]
Vec2 = [True, False, False, True, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, False, False, True]
```

To get a better explanation, let's say *Vec1* is answering "did John drink a coffee today?" and the *Vec2* is answering "did Paul drink a coffee today?". So, what I would like to get with this indicator is the number of days passing between the event "John drinks" and the event "Paul drinks". The logic can be structured as follows:

1) Find the value "True" into the first vector and from that day starts counting; 
2) Keep on counting until you find the "True" into the second vector, from that moment reset the counter.

To fill the empty list of results:

```
ValueInd = []
```

I have so far been able to build up this:

```
trueVector1 = 0
trueVector2 = 0
countAct = False
Count = 0

while len(ValueInd) < len(Vec1):
    while Vec1[trueVector1] == False:
        ValueInd.append(Count)
        trueVector1 += 1
    countAct = True
    trueVector2 = trueVector1
    while countAct == True:
        if Vec2[trueVector2] == True:
            countAct = False
            ValueInd.append(Count)
            Count = 0
            trueVector1 = trueVector2 + 1
        else:
            ValueInd.append(Count)
            trueVector2 += 1
            Count += 1
```

Apart for the horrible structure of the algorithm right now (that I will revise later) I'm not being able to get a proper solution cause this one does not work. While the proper output, according to the data I provided above, should be:

```
ValueInd = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,1,1,0,1,2,1,0,0,0,0]
```

The output that I actually get is:

```
ValueInd = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Can anyone help me with that? Please ask if you need further explanations.

**EXAMPLE**
John drinks a coffee on days 0, 4, 5, 8, 10 on a calendar of 15 days. Paul drinks a coffee on days 2, 4, 7, 8, 11 on a calendar of 15 days. The occurrencies vectors are hence:

```
John = [T, F, F, F, T, T, F, F, T, F, T, F, F, F, F, F]
Paul = [F, F, T, F, T, F, F, T, T, F, F, T, F, F, F, F]
```

The result vector in this example will be:

```
Days = [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

This is because: 
0) John drinks and Paul doesn't, so the count starts with 0;
1) none drinks a coffee so the count increases to 1; 
2) Paul drinks, so the count increases to 2 and then turns off; 
3) No count is activated;
4) Both drinks, so the count starts and ends with 0 on the same day;
5) John drinks, Paul doesn't: so the count is activated and starts with zero;
6) One day without Paul drinking -> count = 1
7) Paul drinks -> count = 2 and resets to 0
8) Both drink, so the count starts with 0 and ends the same day
9) John drinks, so the count starts with 0
10) Paul drinks, so the count ends with 1 
11 - 15) None drinks so the count is always zero.

Comment: It may be me, but seems a bit hard to understand your explanation.

Comment: @RaulGuiu, I'm pretty sure it's me ;) I will try to edit the question and make an example, it's itself a not-so-obvious concept + my not very good explanation skills.

Comment: Not only is it difficult to understand, but from your explanation, the second result seems correct.

Comment: may I gently recommend you http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/? shit like 'ValueInd' is not very acceptable naming style within the python function =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works,

```
def get_counts(Vec1, Vec2):
    c = 0
    counts = []
    counting = False
    for v1, v2 in zip(Vec1, Vec2):
        counts.append(c)
        if v1:
            counting = True
            c = 0
        if v2:
            counting = False
            c = 0
        if counting:
            c += 1
```

E.g.

```
T = True
F = False
John = [T, F, F, F, T, T, F, F, T, F, T, F, F, F, F, F]
Paul = [F, F, T, F, T, F, F, T, T, F, F, T, F, F, F, F]
get_counts(John, Paul)

>>  [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I've tested on my real project and it works perfectly, thanks mate for this. I just point out something for sake of completeness: you're missing a `c = 0` into the `if v1:` block, cause if not the counter does not restart. Thanks for the short clear and (especially) working script!